# Does ADB2C support pre-filled username in first page?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

My situation is customer will first enter their username in my web page , then my backend will check the username is using which service to do the authentication , then route him to ADB2C.

In UX perspective , customer already entered their username in last page , I shouldn’t ask them again in second page of ADB2C page , want to understand does ADB2C could let me passing the username to url or something , so that customer only require to enter password in second page .

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use [login_hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

"During a sign-in user journey, a relying party application may target a specific user or domain name. When targeting a user, an application can specify, in the authorization request, the login_hint query parameter with the user sign-in name. Azure AD B2C automatically populates the sign-in name, while the user only needs to provide the password."